# How to use postman to fully automate uploading a file to an endpoint

Tags: javascript, postman, newman

We are trying to test uploading a file to an endpoint using automation, hoping we can use postman to test.

But we are finding that we may not be able to fully automate it. The Amazon s3 endpoint we want to test only accepts real files, not urls. Postman seems to rely on already having the file for upload downloaded on the users system.

Is there a way we can ensure when another dev goes into our workspaces in postman or tries to run our collection via newman, they don't have to manually download a dependency (file for upload) of the test first, instead letting the tests handle downloading their own dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

After exporting your collection file,
you need to do following steps:

1. place your upload file in the same location where your collections are there.
2. in your request, replace your file name : "./[file name.txt]"

**Before**

```
"body": {
                "mode": "formdata",
                "formdata": [
                    {
                        "key": "black door",
                        "type": "file",
                        "src": "/C:/Users/jbalakr1/Desktop/Postman/na sensor sns.csv"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

**After:**

```
"body": {
                "mode": "formdata",
                "formdata": [
                    {
                        "key": "black door",
                        "type": "file",
                        "src": "./s3-file.csv"
                    }
                ]
            }
```